# How to explain that Ruby "end" invoke method

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

When learning chefspec I have found the below code:

```
describe 'example::default' do
  let(:chef_run) do
    ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new do |node|
      node.set['cookbook']['attribute'] = 'hello'
    end.converge(described_recipe)
  end
end
```

The **end** invoke the method **converge**, I am some new to ruby and chefspec, and I have googled it much time and got no answer, can someone help to explain the syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the same as:

```
x = ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new do |node|
  node.set['cookbook']['attribute'] = 'hello'
end
x.converge(described_recipe)
```

Comment: Worth saying it's done like this so the first access to `chef_run` symbol (in a `expect(chef_run).to` line) will actually call the method and do the convergence of chef run which result will be used to the other calls, the advantage being to converge once and not for each line of test.

Answer (score 5):

The method `converge` is called on the new `ChefSpec::SoloRunner` object.

Have a look at the below example, of initializing an object with a block.

```
Array.new(4) { 5 }.length
# => 4 
Array.new(4) do
  5
end.length
# => 4
Array.new(4) do
  5
end.class
# => Array
```